# How can I have dynamic leading and center alignment for a view in macOS SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want my text be centered for my yellow view and if I make the window size smaller and smaller and the Text reach to the starts, it locks itself and does not go over star. For this goal I made this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Image(systemName: "star")
            
            Spacer()

        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .overlay(alignment: .center, content: {
            
            Text("Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!")
                .lineLimit(1)
            
        })
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .padding()

    }
}
```

The issues:

1 - I cannot have center and leading alignment both together.

2- When the window size get smaller, the Text goes over stars.

3- When the text goes over star it makes wired jump to left and right to adjust for smaller size.

How can I have a center alignment for Text and also stoping the Text going over stars, I put lineLimit for 1 so if text reach to stars I want Text reduce it size from right like:

`Hello, world ...`

The goal would be like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you would have to use the GeometryReader to do this. I'm not sure how just yet but this would not come "for free" with standard layouts.

Comment: Wait... how did you create that video?

Comment: Someone else did this coding but I just have access to gif, now I want to code for myself.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal of having a centered text that does not overlap with the stars even when the window size is reduced, you can use the `frame` modifier with `maxWidth` and `alignment` parameters. Here's the updated code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Image(systemName: "star")

            Text("Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Let's break down the changes:

- We moved the `Text` view inside the `HStack`, so that it can be aligned with the stars.
- We added a frame modifier to the `Text` view with `maxWidth` set to `.infinity`, which means the text can take up the entire available width without going beyond the stars.
- We set the alignment parameter of the frame modifier to `.center`, so that the text is always centered within the available space.
- We removed the `overlay` modifier, as it's not needed for this layout.

With these changes, the text will always be centered and won't overlap with the stars, even when the window size is reduced.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I see the Text is little off center, also with reducing the size of widow Text has wired jump to left and right.

Comment: @HelloCodes if that jump left to right is what I think that's just how text lays itself out in MacOS. It is built to allow small differences in kerning to accommodate the text in the space as best as possible. But that will only ever happen while the user is changing the size of the window... which doesn't happen a lot.

Comment: @Fogmeister: If we chose leading alinement we would not have that jump. But I need center and it has this jump!

Comment: @HelloCodes leading alignment is easy, it always starts x number of pixels from the left. Center alignment changes as each time you change the width of the screen it changes the "start point" of the text. And that has to be accounted for by the way it is calculated. At a very simple level, if there are an odd number of pixels or even number in the width then the layout will have to change etc...

Comment: Please look the updated video, I want some thing like that.